# How to Check Which minSdkVersion is Used in the Flutter App for Android?

Tags: android, flutter, dart

How to check which minSdkVersion is used in the Flutter app for Android? I want to learn what version of minSdkVersion is used in the Flutter app for Android.

Comment: Could you clarify? Do you mean from a compiled binary? Or from source code?  If source code, it's clearly specified in the `pubspec.yaml` file.  What actual problem are you ultimately trying to solve?

Comment: for android build?

Comment: for android build